# Guardar una key en el NDK

Tags: android

Leyendo sobre la mejor forma de guardar una api key en Android, llegué a la conclusión que una buena manera sería guardarla usando C++ en el NDK.

Para esconder una key en el NDK sería algo así:

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <jni.h>

    jstring Java_com_riis_sqlndk_MainActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env,
    jobject javaThis) {
      return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "pass123");
    }
```

La pregunta es... cómo indico en un proyecto Android que quiero escribir en c++?

Aquí el tutorial en cuestión: [ver tutorial](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2268753&seqNum=4)

Saludos

Comment: Acabo de encontrar una libreria que puede ser de utilidad https://github.com/saantiaguilera/android-api-SecureKeys

Comment: gracias @Webserveis, le echaré un ojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser no del todo infalible pero es una buena opción, para poder cargar un modulo, primeramente ve a tu SDK Manager ya que tienes que descargar los 3 paquetes que se muestran en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tu proyecto debe ser creado para incluir este soporte, para esto, al iniciar puedes ver un botón donde seleccionas esta opción, `Include C++ Support`.

Al crear tu proyecto, puedes ver en la estructura de tu proyecto un folder llamado `src/main/cpp` en el cual se creo un archivo llamado `native-lib.cpp`.

Si revisas tu archivo MainActivity, tiene un ejemplo de como implementar el modulo en tu aplicación:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Example of a call to a native method
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
    tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    public native String stringFromJNI();

}
```

Puedes ver 2 cosas nuevas en el código de una clase MainActivity, primeramente este bloque, el cual sirve para configurar 'native-lib' al iniciar la aplicación.

```
 static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
```

y la implementación de un método nativo implementado por la biblioteca native-lib.

```
public native String stringFromJNI();
```

Para configurar el NDK en tu proyecto agrega a tu archivo `local.properties` donde se encuentra la ruta del SDK la del NDK, con esto tu proyecto estará listo.

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\jorgesys\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\jorgesys\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
```

Encontré un excelente tutorial en espanol para realizar esto:
[Cómo ejecutar código C desde Android con el NDK](https://sg.com.mx/buzz/tutorial-como-ejecutar-codigo-c-android-el-ndk#.WKFCSRIrJEK)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la librería [SecureKeys](https://github.com/saantiaguilera/android-api-SecureKeys) aun no la he probado, pero tiene buena pinta si funciona:

Para guardar las claves:

```
@SecureKeys({
    @SecureKey(key = "key_api_googlemaps", value = "aD98E2GEk23TReYds9Zs9zdSdDBi23EAsdq29fXkpsDwp0W+h"),
    @SecureKey(key = "key_other", value = "otra clave...")
})
```

Y para recuperar la clave:

`SecureEnvironment.getString("key_api_googlemaps");`

**Seguridad en guardar la claves**

> This library uses an annotationProcessor to store the constants in a
>   new file (where the constants are encrypted), and via JNI it will
>   later retrieve them decoding them inside the .so file.
>
> This way the attackers cant know the encoding system (because its
>   inside the annotation processor), neither the decoding.
>
> Note: They can still "find" the class with the crypted constants or do
>   a heapdump of the map inside the .so file. But since its encrypted
>   they will have a (way too much) harder time figuring the constants
>   out.

Comment: imagino que eso luego lo ofusca y en el apk no es fácil de encontrar verdad?

Comment: para lo que entiendo la librería lo que hace al dar compilar, crea un archivo .so donde almacena las claves cifradas en AES, que solo puede recuperarse con el jni, no domino mucho el tema, si realmente se puede recuperar externamente, es decir dentro del apk, se vea.